# How to convert trigonometric values to AlgebraicNumber

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

It is known that trigonometric functions evaluated at rational numbers of degrees are algebraic, and Mathematica recognize this: for example

```
Sin[20 °] ∈ Algebraics // FullSimplify
```

gives `True`. But i can't find any function that convert this number to `AlgebraicNumber`
(in the example, it would be `AlgebraicNumber[Root[-1 - 3 #1 + #1^3 &, 3], {0, 1/2, 0}]` but i had to do some manipulations with trigonometric functions to get that representation).

Is there a Mathematica function to do this in general automatically?

Comment: I don' t know of a function that will do this, but perhaps [`RootApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant) will work for you? For example, `RootApproximant[N[Sin[20 Degree], 100]`.

Comment: @Bill ToRadicals couldn't work in general because most of this algebraic numbers will be of degree higher that 5 and chances are that they don't are expressible as radicals.

Comment: @CarlWoll That seems to work perfectly with easy examples. Thanks!
Probably with complicated examples, the precision parameter of N would need to be increased, but one wouldn't know how much is necessary.

Comment: Rather than use `RootApproximant` use `Sin[20 Degree] // FunctionExpand // RootReduce`

Comment: Oh, I see!, RootReduce and ToNumberField work as I expected, they just needed Degree to be expanded! Thank you, @BobHanlon

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = Sin[20 Degree];
```

Use [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) to convert [`Degree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Degree.html) to radians

```
Degree // FunctionExpand

(* π/180 *)
```

Once the argument of [`Sin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) is converted to radians, [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) converts the expression to a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) function.

```
(expr2 = expr // FunctionExpand // RootReduce) // InputForm

(* Root[-3 + 36*#1^2 - 96*#1^4 + 64*#1^6 & , 4, 0] *)

expr == expr2 // N

(* True *)
```

Similarly, with [`ToNumberField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumberField.html)

```
(expr3 = expr // FunctionExpand // ToNumberField) // InputForm

(* AlgebraicNumber[
 Root[1 - #1^6 + #1^12 & , 12, 0], {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, -1/2}] *)
```

This simplifies to `expr2`

```
(expr3 // FullSimplify) === expr2

(* True *)
```

or

```
(expr3 // RootReduce) === expr2

(* True *)
```